# plot different colours based on criteria within ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the plot below, I can subset each df by colour but is there a way I can set an extra condition within ggplot to plot any depths greater than 5m in a different colour?

I know how to create a subset of the data outside of ggplot (where I subset the df higher and lower than 5m respectively into two df) then import all 4 different data frames into ggplot to make the figure. but is there a way to set this condition within ggplot? For example, if I want depth greater than 5 to be a different colour, then for df 1, the first would be at 6m and df2 would be at 5m to change colours.

I can't do this manually in my df because im dealing with thousands of datapoints hence why im trying to figure out if there is a quicker way within ggplot.

```
depth1 <- c(1, 3, 6, 8, 10, 14, 16, 19, 20, 22)
depth2 <- c(2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 14, 15, 16, 25)

var1 <- c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 17, 18, 20, 22) 
var2 <- c(3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 13, 15, 19, 22) 

var3 <- c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13, 15, 17)
var4 <- c(1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 14, 15)

df1 <- cbind(depth1, var1, var3)
df2 <- cbind(depth2, var2, var4)

 (plot <- ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=var1, y=var2)) + geom_point(colour="black") +
      geom_point(data=df2, aes(x=var2, y=var4), colour="red"))
```

Comment: use `cut()` to define your categories, then add a `color` mapping to your `aes` statement ...

Answer (score 1):

You can assign `color` to a vector created by `ifelse` inside `aes`. This does not need to be a vector of color names, rather just a vector of the labels you wish applied to the legend, for example `color = ifelse(depth1 > 5, 'High', 'Low')`

It's not clear from the question whether you want `df1` and `df2` to have the same colors, differing only by depth. If so, then you could do:

```r
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(x = var1, y = var2, color = ifelse(depth1 > 5, 'High', 'Low')),
             data = df1) +
  geom_point(aes(x = var3, y = var4, color = ifelse(depth2 > 5, 'High', 'Low')), 
             data = df2) +
  scale_color_manual('Depth', values = c(Low = 'black', High = 'red'))
```

[image]

If you want a different color scheme for each data set, then you just need to ensure that the `ifelse` produces unique results for each series:

```r
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 4, aes(x = var1, y = var2, 
                 fill = ifelse(depth1 > 5, 'High (df1)', 'Low (df1)')),
             data = df1) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 4, aes(x = var3, y = var4,
                 fill = ifelse(depth2 > 5, 'High (df2)', 'Low (df2)')), 
             data = df2) +
  scale_fill_manual('Depth', values = c(`Low (df1)`  = 'red3', 
                                        `High (df1)` = 'pink',
                                        `Low (df2)`  = 'navy', 
                                        `High (df2)` = 'cornflowerblue')) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16)
```

[image]